# Is there any easy way to "provide" more permissions for my facebook connect app, using sfFacebookConnect

Tags: facebook, api, symfony1

From what I see now, it seems that the plugin provides me only authenticated facebook user's email address.I need the first name, last name, and other data.

Answer (score 3):

With my plugin (few month ago) the facebook_connect setting in app.yml did not work.

So, I've put this for the fb login button :

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=*ID_CLIENT*&redirect_uri=<?=urlencode("http://*YOUR_URL_CALLBACK*")?>&scope=email,user_birthday,publish_stream&response_type=token"><img src="/images/fb_dark_medium_short.gif" alt="Facebook Connect" style="width:100px"/></a>
```

You can add in the scope GET parameter your permissions.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

by setting:

```
facebook_connect:
  user_permissions: []
```

you can request some of those permission: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: That setting is for adding permissions in 'sf_user_permissions' table for the newly created user.That not what I meant.This setting do not refer to Facebook's authentication permissions.